# Should one use sanitizers with optimization on or off?

Tags: c++, sanitizer

I know that ideally one should do both builds(and obviously run the exes), but assuming that for resource reasons you can do only one which one would you pick.

I am interested if I should enable optimization or not.

My intuition says prefer optimized build because it is more likely to make UB visible due to optimizations, but I am not sure I am right.

Comment: Note: optimizations do not trigger UB, UB might be hidden until an optimization reveals the bug.

Comment: If you ask about testing, I think, you should rather test the optimized builds, because that's what your customers get.

Comment: You should test what you ship out.

Comment: If you have enough resources to run a sanitizer on an unoptimized build, you have resources to run it on both versions. The two tend to be an order of magnitude or more apart in terms of running time.